# What is the approximation of $\frac{(2n + 1)(3n - 5)}{\sqrt{n^2 - 73}}$ for large $n$?

Tags: limits

What is the approximation of
$$\frac{(2n + 1)(3n - 5)}{\sqrt{n^2 - 73}}$$ for large $n$?

I got the following but the book I am reading says that the answer is $\frac{1}{n}$,

$$\frac{(2n + 1)(3n - 5)}{\sqrt{n^2 - 73}} = \frac{6n^2 - 7n - 5}{\sqrt{n^2 - 73}}$$

$\therefore$ for large $n$ (ignoring the $6$), $\frac{n^2}{n} = n$

Comment: Yes, it should be $6n$

Answer (score 2):

So, we have:
$$\sqrt{n^2-73}\sim n$$
When $n\to +\infty$ (we don't have to use the absolute value).

The numerator is a polynomial of degree $2$. We can show that in general a polynomial of the form $a_n x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_0\,\, \sim\,\, a_n x^n$ when $n \to +\infty$.

So, your limit is:
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(2n + 1)(3n - 5)}{\sqrt{n^2 - 73}}\,\,\sim \,\, \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{6n^2}{n}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}6n=+\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

$(6n^2-7n-5)(n^2-73)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

$=(6n-7-\frac{5}{n})(1-\frac{73}{n^2})^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

By binomial expansion,

$=(6n-7-\frac{5}{n})(1+\frac{73}{2n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^4}))$

$=6n-7+\frac{214}{n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})$

WolframAlpha gives the forth term $-\frac{511}{2n^2}$:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%286n%5E2-7n-5%29%28n%5E2-73%29%5E%28-1%2F2%29